# Git command could not be found. Please create an alias or add it to your PATH

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

After updating github, I am getting these `WARNING`.

> git command could not be found. Please create an alias or add it to your PATH.
>
> Warning: Could not find ssh-agent.

When I am trying any `commands`, I get error messages.

After searching, I found other people are facing similar problem. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950355/git-command-could-not-be-found-and-could-not-find-ssh-agent). But they are suggesting to re-install github.

Is there any other solution expect re-installing github?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem: "Maybe git-rebase is broken": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346755/maybe-git-rebase-is-broken"

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Short version**

To fix it

- close **Git Shell**
- open **GitHub** and let it do some post installation.
- Open **Git Shell** again and you should be fixed.

**Long version**

Just to make sure I follow you, you just did this

- Open **Git Shell**
- You are prompted to update **GitHub**
- After the update, **Git Shell** opens

Now it gives the error

> git command could not be found. Please create an alias or add it to
> your PATH.
>
> Warning: Could not find ssh-agent.

If this is the case, do this

- Close **Git Shell**
- Now open the **GitHub** application (not *Git Shell*).

This will say something along the lines of (not sure of the exact version)

> GitHub is extracting git..

Let that go through the process and after it is complete, go open **Git Shell** and it is fixed. Just worked for me at least.

Comment: Awesome. Just opened the GitHub and got the message of GitHub is extracting git.. Later open the git shell, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could try to add git to your path.

Go to Start -> Right click My Computer -> Properties

Go to Advanced system settings

Press Environment Variables...

Find Path and press Edit

Enter ";PATH to git.exe file" at the end of the path.

Reboot

Comment: I did the same, and it worked!! thnks